# How to convert dockerfile commands to maven xml entries?

Tags: java, xml, maven, docker, dockerfile

I am dockerizing my Java applications by maven docker plugin. 
I found a simple docker-maven-plugin that creates a simple docker file.. 
I want to know how to convert docker file command such as ADD,COPY,VOLUME etc. in to maven xml entries ? 
I mean I need to be able to customize my dockerfile through maven pom.xml
I could not find any documentations or tutorial for this ...

Thanks for your input.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with docker? Obtain a release image? Run integration test?

Comment: the maven plugin is documented on [its github](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: which plugin are you using? The answer depends on it.

Comment: @Aaron spotify's plugin Github page asks to use more opinionated version for new projects.

Comment: @diginoise yes, that's a good reason for OP to read the documentation of its plugin (or name it explicitly, if what you're thinking is that he's using another plugin than the "docker-maven-plugin" he mentioned)

Comment: I've talked too quickly, there are multiple maven plugin with the artifactId `docker-maven-plugin`. OP, can you clarify which it is? (edit its groupId in your question)

Comment: I use com.spotify plugin .. my pom.xml file is almost same as this https://github.com/deege/deegeu-maven-java-docker-example

Comment: More specifically, in my application I need to read and pars a data set file into the application. So I should somehow include the data set file in to my container. I tried using volumes but I don't know why still I get java.io.FileNotFoundException. I do: sudo docker run -it -v /home/myusername/Desktop/DataSet:/usr/DataSet --name myapp myimagename bash

Comment: @Aaron, any comment ?

Comment: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#use-a-dockerfile ? Otherwise I'm not too sure. I'd recommend testing the maven packaging and docker image build separately as a first step before trying to integrate the docker aspect into maven